# Grails webflow: merging a new set of params with an existing flow variable

Tags: grails, spring-webflow

I'm trying to populate a domain class across several steps. I'm having trouble "merging" the new params into the existing flow variable. Below you will see how i'm currently doing it (ie individually setting the domain class fields from the params object).

Is there a better way to do this?

```
class UserController {
    def scaffold = User

    def index = {
        redirect(action:'registration')
    }
    def registrationFlow = {
        register1 {
            on("continue") {
                transient user = new User(params)
                flow.user = user
                if(!user.validate(['loginName', 'password'])) {
                    return error()
                }
            }.to "register2"
        }
        register2 {
            on("register") {
                transient user = flow.user;
                //TODO: is there a better way to merge the flow.user with the params?
                user.firstName = params.firstName;
                user.lastName = params.lastName;
                user.preferredEmail = params.preferredEmail;
                if(!user.validate()) {
                    return error()
                }
            }.to "registerFinal"
            on("return").to "register1"
        }
        registerFinal ()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define an array of allowed fields per page and restrict to these field name by using binddata:

```
def validFieldsRegister2 = ["firstName", "lastName", "prefferedEmail"]
bindData(user, params,  [include: validFieldsRegister2])
```